# Bubble chat do not show again with the same content in android 13?

Tags: android-13, android-bubbles

I am handling a chat app with a disabled preview message feature, so when receive a new message, I show a bubble with the text "You have a new message".

In the first time it work fine, **but after user close this bubble** then it is not shown again, there are nothings in the status bar also and i just see the unread badge in launcher icon.

**Note: **This case is opcurs in android 12 and 13, I have tested in android 11 and it still work fine.

I think there is a rule or the issue of OS but i dont find any document about this. I also to try with ([sameple bubble chat app of google](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/People) but nothing diffenrent.

Please give me some document or information about this issue, thank in advance!

This is my code to show bubble chat:

```
fun showNotification(chat: Chat, fromUser: Boolean, update: Boolean = false) {
        updateShortcuts(chat.contact)
        val icon = IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmapContentUri(chat.contact.iconUri)
        val user = Person.Builder().setName(context.getString(R.string.sender_you)).build()
        val person = Person.Builder().setName(chat.contact.name).setIcon(icon).build()
        val contentUri = "https://android.example.com/chat/${chat.contact.id}".toUri()

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            REQUEST_BUBBLE,
            // Launch BubbleActivity as the expanded bubble.
            Intent(context, BubbleActivity::class.java)
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setData(contentUri),
            flagUpdateCurrent(mutable = true)
        )
        // Let's add some more content to the notification in case it falls back to a normal
        // notification.
        val messagingStyle = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(user)
        val lastId = chat.messages.last().id
        for (message in chat.messages) {
            val m = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
                "You have a new message",
                message.timestamp,
                if (message.isIncoming) person else null
            ).apply {
                if (message.photoUri != null) {
                    setData(message.photoMimeType, message.photoUri)
                }
            }
            if (message.id < lastId) {
                messagingStyle.addHistoricMessage(m)
            } else {
                messagingStyle.addMessage(m)
            }
        }

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_NEW_MESSAGES)
            // A notification can be shown as a bubble by calling setBubbleMetadata()
            .setBubbleMetadata(
                NotificationCompat.BubbleMetadata.Builder(pendingIntent, icon)
                    // The height of the expanded bubble.
                    .setDesiredHeight(context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bubble_height))
                    .apply {
                        // When the bubble is explicitly opened by the user, we can show the bubble
                        // automatically in the expanded state. This works only when the app is in
                        // the foreground.
                        if (fromUser) {
                            setAutoExpandBubble(true)
                        }
                        if (fromUser || update) {
                            setSuppressNotification(true)
                        }
                    }
                    .build()
            )
            // The user can turn off the bubble in system settings. In that case, this notification
            // is shown as a normal notification instead of a bubble. Make sure that this
            // notification works as a normal notification as well.
            .setContentTitle(chat.contact.name)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setShortcutId(chat.contact.shortcutId)
            // This ID helps the intelligence services of the device to correlate this notification
            // with the corresponding dynamic shortcut.
            .setLocusId(LocusIdCompat(chat.contact.shortcutId))
            .addPerson(person)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            // The content Intent is used when the user clicks on the "Open Content" icon button on
            // the expanded bubble, as well as when the fall-back notification is clicked.
            .setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    REQUEST_CONTENT,
                    Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        .setData(contentUri),
                    flagUpdateCurrent(mutable = false)
                )
            )
            // Direct Reply
            .addAction(
                NotificationCompat.Action
                    .Builder(
                        IconCompat.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.ic_send),
                        context.getString(R.string.label_reply),
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            context,
                            REQUEST_CONTENT,
                            Intent(context, ReplyReceiver::class.java).setData(contentUri),
                            flagUpdateCurrent(mutable = true)
                        )
                    )
                    .addRemoteInput(
                        RemoteInput.Builder(ReplyReceiver.KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
                            .setLabel(context.getString(R.string.hint_input))
                            .build()
                    )
                    .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
                    .build()
            )
            // Let's add some more content to the notification in case it falls back to a normal
            // notification.
            .setStyle(messagingStyle)
            .setWhen(chat.messages.last().timestamp)
        // Don't sound/vibrate if an update to an existing notification.
        if (update) {
            builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(chat.contact.id.toInt(), builder.build())
    }
```